# Calling a Method of parent form in showdialog of child form in Compact Framework Causing ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, invoke

I am calling a ShowDialog of a form from my parent form and i am Populating some data in the child form Through which i want to call a method in my parent form.

The method in my parent form updates controls values in my form.

this is causing me a threadabort exception

Say like

```
ChildForm Cform=new ChildForm();
Cform.ShowDialog();
```

and in ChildForm

```
ParentForm PForm=new Parentform();
PForm.Somemethod();//method in my parentForm
```

In somemethod I am updating the values of the controls in the form by invoking

I am invoking each Control but still I am getting the *ThreadAbort Exception*

**Note: I am using Compact Framework**

```
//My parent Form Method
       public void ProcessResponse()
        {

            Result Objresult = new Result();

            Objresult.ShowDialog();

        }

    //My child Form
      public void SendBackResponse()
      {
      //Some Processing
       ParentForm PForm=new Parentform();
        PForm.Somemethod();
      }

And In ParentForm I am having 

    public void Somemethod()
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
         //I am invoking Through the delegate
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Post relevant code. this code is not helpful enough

Comment: @SriramSakthivel please look the Edited Post

Comment: Are you calling `Thread.Abort` anywhere?

Comment: If you are not threading anything, there is no reason to invoke.

Comment: Also, `ChildForm` should not be creating an instance of `ParentForm`. Instead, create a **ParentForm** Property in `ChildForm` that you can set before showing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here.

First, your "parent" form, isn't the Form that called ShowDialog.  You're actually creating a whole new Form instance in the Child, so it will not be the same as the Parent that created the Child.

Second, ShowDialog creates a separate message pump for the Dialog being shown.  Any Windows Messages sent to the Parent are not going to get handled until the Dialog closes and the main message pump starts running again.  That means that any UI updates on the parent are not going to happen until the Dialog closes.

Third, what you doing is just bad design.  If you need the Parent to react in some UI way to the Child, then expose a property in the Child, read it when the Child Closes and handle the updates:

```
class Child : Form
{
    ....
    public string NewInfo { get; set; }
}

....

// code in the Parent
var child = new ChildForm();
if(child.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   this.UseChildData(child.NewInfo);
}
```

If you aren't updating the parent UI, but running some form of business logic, then you're violating separation of concerns.  Put that business logic into a Presenter/Controller/ViewModel/Service/Model/whatever and pass that along to the child.

```
class Service
{
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        // business logic here 
    } 
}

class Child : Form
{
    Service m_service;

    public Child(Service service)
    {
        m_service = service;
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        // call the business logic
        m_service.DoSomething();
    }
}

....

// code in the Parent
var svc = new Service();
....
var child = new ChildForm(svc);
child.ShowDialog();
```